# In my wordpress website the Yoast SEO plugin doesn't display the search console to setting option for Google Authorization Code button

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I am facing a big problem for  yoast seo plugin. Here **when I click search console option from menu it doesn't show the setting option for Google Authorization Code button.** Please see the image I have attached.

I don't find this setting option anyway. Please anyone help me. I will be too much happy. Thanks advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Been killing myself trying to figure this out too for an hour or so. 
I had been seeing a lot of people asking the same thing but here is the answer!

https://yoast.com/where-did-my-search-console-errors-go/

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on your answer and post here what it should be done? Just a URL it's gonna be considered a poor answer and maybe excluded.